# Machine Learning Training Perspective

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

I just need some guidance. I'm seeing a lot of directions to go and I want to see what would be my best Avenue. So essentially I have a pandas dataframe of groups similar to this(groups are in 4's):

```
Name                        Role    XP    Acumen
0   Johnny Tsunami        Driver    1000      39
1   Michael B. Jackson    Pistol    2500      46
2   Bobby Zuko            Pistol    3000      50
3   Greg Ritcher         Lookout    200       25
4   Johnny Tsunami        Driver    1000      39
5   Michael B. Jackson    Pistol    2500      46
6   Bobby Zuko            Pistol    3000      50
7   Appa Derren          Lookout    250       30
8   Baby Hitsuo           Driver    950       35
9   Michael B. Jackson    Pistol    2500      46
10  Bobby Zuko            Pistol    3000      50
11  Appa Derren          Lookout    250       30
```

So basically I want to train the model to pick similar groups based of the dataframe above. End goal is I want to give it a massive dataset and have it pick out rows to create groups similar to the one above. Maybe refine it so it picks out similar numbers accuracy in values.

What's the best route to take? Supervised unsupervised. Linear....k clusters? Where do I need to point my research. What are the best steps to take.

Comment: Not a coding question, and nothing to do with `python`(tag removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I would take is to understand how you want to calculate the similarity in the above mentioned data that seems fairly categorical. The most basic approach would be to run a clustering/ classification algorithm (mostly unsupervised in your case). Personally, even `k-means` runs fairly quickly and accurately if you have no idea of how to proceed (DBSCAN is my fav). I would also do an exploratory analysis (Self-Organizing Maps/ Kohonen Maps maybe useful in your case) to understand how the data is distributed.

You want to create groups and compare the groups to one another on after your clustering/ classification, right? You will also need to come up with a similarity metric like the KL Divergence to compare.

The main issue is coming up with a 'k' that will cluster your data, but I feel like you will need to try out different values and your intuition will play an important role!

Links: 
SOM: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16566459
DBSCAN: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan
KL Divergence/ Cross-Entropy Loss: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the links. It was a broad question but you definitely narrowed my search. I've been looking through the links you've posted and this looks like exactly what I'm looking. Thank you for your amazing assistance.